# Apple GCC 4.2.1 passing a pointer to constructor

Tags: c++, alignment

Let's say I have a class and there are no visible problems with it or its members, however if I try to pass the addresses of several class members to another class in the same module, the first argument is being passed correctly, but the second one is always **NULL**! How can this be? Could there be some kind of hidden stack / heap corruption or some kind of alignment problem? There are no problems in **MSVC**, though...

```
class myType2
{
     char c1;
     char c2;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (1))); // Yes, align differs and I can't change it

class MyClass2
{
public:
    MyClass2(myType1* type1, myType2* type2, int data)
    {
         // type1 and data are ok, but type2 is NULL...
    }
} __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));

class MyClass
{
public:
    myType1 type1;
    myType2 type2;
    //....
    void test()
    {
        MyClass2 test1(&this->type1, &this->type2, 170);
        MyClass2* pTest2 = new MyClass2(&this->type1, &this->type2, 170); // Same result

        myType2 localType2;
        MyClass2 test3(&this->type1, &localType2, 170); // Same result!!!
    }
} __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
```

Comment: Works for me in a ppc mac with gcc 4.0. Can you show a complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes, the simplified example works fine, as always. There is no way I can show you a complete example, since its hundreds of thousands of lines of code...

Comment: I have tried a lot of variations, but it seems that no matter what kind of data I pass, only first argument is passed correctly... Something's definitely wrong with stack :(

Comment: How are we supposed to find your problem then?

Comment: Well, maybe somebody has encountered this kind of problem and can give me some advice? Maybe there is some kind of limitation of data, which can be passed on stack in GCC or something like that?

Comment: Its probably a compiler bug.  Perhaps one thing to try is setting an explicit calling convention on the constructor of MyClass2.

Comment: Double check your compiler settings! Maybe one object file is compiled with slightly different settings than the other. See if sizeof (MyClass) and sizeof (myType1*) are the same on both the calling and the receiving side.

Comment: Since you know that simplified example is forking just fine, the only conclusion is that this code has no error per se. I guess, this is the answer to your question. So the code is not relevant to the root of the problem. BTW (just a guess): did you overload the "&" operator for myType2?

Comment: Avp, there is no operators overloading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blasted GCC... :doubleFacePalm I wasn't able to solve this problem normally, but I found a workaround by passing all class constructor data in a structure aligned by 16 bytes boundary.